# Is there a way to put one type of Entity into more than one room?

Tags: android, android-room

Right now I'm trying to migrate a database from the older CursorLoader-based queries to the newer Room-Entity one. However, said database had a case of one entity being extended into 7 others and put into separate tables, each of said entities being exactly the same with the exception of their table names.

Is there a way I can do that with Room queries? I heard it's ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one master table that is connected to other tables then you should use Relationship Between tables By using Entity Classes

Here is the full tutorial you can.
https://medium.com/@magdamiu/android-room-persistence-library-relations-75bbe02e8522